# How to get two HTML section blocks align in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code with two Section blocks following each other vertically, I want them to be aligned horizontally. To do so, I put them the attribute inline-block in the position parameter in my CSS but it doesn't work.

Here is my code :

**HTML**

```
<section class="desc-block-left">
<img class="icon"src="img/scolarite.png" alt="Scolarité">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem, quos, perspiciatis reiciendis explicabo possimus vel culpa fugiat voluptatum laboriosam hic adipisci dicta itaque sed ipsum assumenda! Alias voluptatum blanditiis beatae?
</p>
<ul>
<li><img src="img/tools-info2.png" alt="Info"></li>
<li><img src="img/tools-fav2.png" alt="Fav"></li>
</ul>
</section>
<section class="desc-block-right">
<img class="icon"src="img/scolarite.png" alt="Scolarité">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem, quos, perspiciatis reiciendis explicabo possimus vel culpa fugiat voluptatum laboriosam hic adipisci dicta itaque sed ipsum assumenda! Alias voluptatum blanditiis beatae?
</p>
<ul>
<li><img src="img/tools-info2.png" alt="Info"></li>
<li><img src="img/tools-fav2.png" alt="Fav"></li>
</ul>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
/*LAYOUT LEFT COLUMN*/

.desc-block-left{
    position:inline-block;
    border-style:solid;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    width:40%;
    height:110px;
    margin:30px 10px 100px 150px;
    border-radius:10px;
}

.icon{
    float:left;
    margin:5px;
}

.desc-block-left p{
    position:inline-block;
    float:left;
    margin:5px;
    width:70%;
    text-align:justify;
}

.desc-block-left ul{
   display:inline-block;
}

.desc-block-left ul li{
    position:inline;
    margin:10 5 10 5;
    list-style:none; 
}

/*LAYOUT RIGHT COLUMN*/

.desc-block-right{
    position:inline-block;
    border-style:solid;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    width:40%;
    height:110px;
    margin:30px 10px 100px 150px;
    border-radius:10px;
}

.desc-block-right p{
    position:inline-block;
    float:left;
    margin:5px;
    width:70%;
    text-align:justify;
}

.desc-block-right ul{
   display:inline-block;
}

.desc-block-right ul li{
    position:inline;
    margin:10 5 10 5;
    list-style:none; 
}
```

Comment: Replace every `position:inline-block | inline` with `display:inline-block | inline` it will be breaking whole CSS

Comment: @DhavalMarthak I don't really get what you mean, putting everything in inline effectively breaks it all.

Comment: There is no such setting as `position:inline-block;`, try 'display:inline-block` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, float doesnt really solve the problem and is often not a good practice as it gets in the way for later UI flexibility. However, @Mela is correct suggesting that the margin is the most probable cause for the error, as 80% + 360px unlikely will fit to align horizontally into most containers. That would only leave 24px on a 1920px wide screen.

By making the margin to the right percentage-based however, it works. You should consider this for the left margin as well if you want to stick to inline-blocks, which i suggest.

If you dont want percentage-based margins however, you should set your section width to px as well. Mixing px and % is for the most time a bad idea, due to mystical problems as the one you're experiencing are bound to emerge.

```
 .desc-block-left1 {
    display:inline-block;
    border-style:solid;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    width:40%;
    height:110px;
    margin:30px 10px 10px 5%;
    border-radius:10px;
}
 .desc-block-right1 {
    display:inline-block;
    border-style:solid;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    width:40%;
    height:110px;
    margin:30px 10px 10px 5%;
    border-radius:10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dnGy5/ (purged from lorem and imgs as they only served as a distraction in the matter)

Answer (score 0):

```
.desc-block-left{ float:left; }
.desc-block-right{ float:right; }
```

Why don't you use simply apply a float to the blocks? Remember that in this way, display:inline-block; it's useless.
Other thing. The margin value is really high, so if you don't have a large content they will never align horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

First,

```
position: inline-block;
```

Should really be:

```
display: inline-block;
```

Then the problem:
`inline-block` has a problem with whitespaces. If there is a white space between two elements that are displayed with inline-block, the white space will be accounted for. (By white space I mean the carriage return we use to format our HTML code for readability).

```
<section>  
...  
</section>    (this carriage return is considered a whitespace)  
<section>  
...
</section>
```

Which means a nice 50% section, followed by another 50% section will be displayed as 50% + white space + 50%. Having the second column fall on the next line. Now however you calculate your percentages there always will be the extra space(s) to mess it up.

The solution(s):

My favorite is to put a comment between the two elements. It keep readability and fixes the problem cleanly.

```
<section>
...
</section><!--    (this comment is not considered a whitespace)
--><section>
...
</section>
```

Or, you could open the second tag right after closing the first:

```
<section>
...
</section><section>
...
</section>
```